# How to save output from Command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file

I know the general syntax to save the output to a text file while executing in command prompt.

But my need is different. I want to see it in the Command prompt window also I want to save it in text file. USually using > c:\dirlist.txt will save to text file but cant see in command prompt window.

I need to see in command prompt as well as save in text file. Any help

Comment: Voted to transfer the question to SuperUser, since it's more appropriate for that site.

Answer (score 2):

At first, it is relatively easy to write a TEE.BAT program. The only problem is that `set /p` command (used to get the output from the command) doesn't differentiate between the end of file and an empty line. This mean that the output will be captured until the first empty line (or the end of file):

```
@echo off
:: usage: AnyCommand | TEE filename
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if exist %1 del %1
:nextLine
set line=:EOF
set /p line=
if "!line!" == ":EOF" goto :eof
echo(!line!
echo(!line!>> %1
goto nextLine
```

You may test that this Batch file indeed works this way:

```
tee CopyOfFile.txt < File.txt
```

**However**, when this Batch file is used in the way it was designed, it fails now and then:

```
type File.txt | tee CopyOfFile.txt
```

Previous line sometimes works ok and sometimes show and store just the first line of the file. I made several tests and can not isolate the cause of the error. Perhaps someone (jeb?) could explain what is happening in this case and give a solution.

Comment: I examine it at [How Set/p works](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=9781#p9781). set/p doesn't wait for the data from a pipe, and set/p can't read data with `<LF>` only, but pipes remove the `<CR>`

Comment: My last sentence is nonsense. The pipe buffer contains the `CR/LF` pairs, `set/p` reads always the complete (pipe) buffer, but removes all after the first `CR/LF`, so you can lose lines

Answer (score 1):

You want the equivalent of the `tee` program for Windows. If you can use [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell), then [you already have what you need](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29#Windows_PowerShell_2). Otherwise, google for an implementation that works on your system.

Alternatively, you could redirect the output to a file and observe that file with a live log viewer from another command prompt (i.e. the equivalent of `tail`).

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own tee with batch, like the one of Aacini, but without the drawbacks.

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%A in ('findstr /n "^" ') do (
  set "line=%%A"
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  set "line=!line:*:=!"
  (echo(!line!)
  (echo(!line!) > "%~1"
  endlocal
)
```

The initially idea is from walid2me [echo to screen and file in a single line](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?pid=5221#p5221)

Answer (score 0):

The following is another approach for displaying and Logging command output:

```
@Echo off & CD "%~dp0"
For /F "UsebackQ Tokens=* Delims=" %%A in (`"%~1"`) do (
    >>Outputfile.txt Echo(%%A
    Echo(%%A
)
Goto :EOF
```

Comment: Used either as a subroutine or stand alone batch file, and call it with the command to be output in qouted form. Depending on quoting within the command, it may be necessary to assign the command to a variable first and pass the variable in the call.